# Finding birth father in the Merchant Marine?

Tags: united-states, merchant-navy

I was told my birth father is from the Seattle WA area. He was adopted and is of American Indian descent. I know his name but am not publishing it here as he is less than 100 years old.

In 1967 he was in the Merchant Marine, and a letter I found said something like he couldn't wait to see my mom when his ship comes into Frisco. I think he was a little older than my mom and she was born in 1950. How can I search the merchant marine records; and what other avenues should I explore?

Comment: Hi, Heidi, I've removed your father's name as it is against our rules to the name of a living (or possibly living) person: see https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @sean007 The purpose of the site is to answer questions -- to share research tips and strategies. It's not a query board where people can gain rep simply by doing lookups.

Comment: Well sure that confirms the point that I was making. Without a name to work from there is no starting point to work from ?

Comment: @sean007 You don't need a name to identify methods and record sources that might help the OP **AND OTHERS**

Comment: @sean007 Please familiarize yourself with the privacy policy, which can be found here. https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic   Someone who has already done research in this topic should be able to write an answer without having the name of the questioner's research subject.

Comment: Hi, Heidi -- do you have the name of the ship he served on?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you can obtain Merchant Marine records from the [Coast Guard](https://www.dco.uscg.mil/Our-Organization/Assistant-Commandant-for-Prevention-Policy-CG-5P/National-Maritime-Center-NMC/record_request/) (see **Mariner Record Requests** and **Request Information**). Though it sounds like you may not have enough information to be able to complete the request.

Their website says:

> Merchant Mariners, or their next-of-kin, may obtain copies of their
>   records, but the National Maritime Center (NMC) may not disclose an
>   individual’s personal record without:
>
> - Written and/or notarized consent of the mariner,
> - Power of Attorney, or
> - by providing a certified copy of a Death Certificate.

and

> You must include the required information in writing in order for us
>   to process your request:
>
> - Nature of the request,
> - Requester and mariner’s full name,
> - Reference or social security number,
> - Mariner’s date of birth,
> - Contact information address and phone number.

Without knowing what you're trying to do, I can't suggest any other avenues to explore.